# Python + Selenium. Как проверить то, что таблица с подсказками появилась в поисковике?

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

Как сделать проверку, что таблица с подсказками появилась после того, как автотест введет туда Google например?

[image: Пример]

Comment: посмотрите в инструментах разработчика какие html элементы создаются. Потом ожидайте их создания как любые другие элементы e.g.: `WebDriverWait(driver, timeout).until(EC.presence_of_element_located(selector))`

Answer (score 1):

Если нужно просто проверить, что есть подсказки (без проверки корректности подсказок), то достаточно получить их количество и проверить, что оно больше 0.

Определяем локатор элемента списка подсказок (элементы это "диск", "docs" и т.д.) и получаем список вебэлементов. Для получения списка можно воспользоваться классом `visibility_of_element_located`, так как нам не достаточно простого наличия элементов в DOM, необходимо, чтобы они были видимы.

```
locator = (By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'ul > li') # просто пример, необходимо вставить свое значение
timeout = 30 # время ожидания
elements = WebDriverWait(driver, timeout).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located(locator))
assert elements
```